# On LeetCode, why do "lists" behave like objects, with a `.val` and `.next` property?

Tags: python

https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/editorial/

On the leetcode website, there is a "Add Two Number" practice. My questions is, how does l1.val or l2.val work? I thought l1 is a list which is [2, 4, 3]. How does l1.val calling integer 2?
Or it's from class ListNode? I'm confused..

Code solution as below:

```
 Definition for singly-linked list.
 class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
         self.val = val
         self.next = next
```

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        dummyHead = ListNode(0)
        curr = dummyHead
        carry = 0
        while l1 != None or l2 != None or carry != 0:
            l1Val = l1.val if l1 else 0
            l2Val = l2.val if l2 else 0
            columnSum = l1Val + l2Val + carry
            carry = columnSum // 10
            newNode = ListNode(columnSum % 10)
            curr.next = newNode
            curr = newNode
            l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
            l2 = l2.next if l2 else None
        return dummyHead.next
```

There are l1 = [2, 4, 3] and l2 = [5, 6, 4]. I thought to access the integer inside the list, you need to write l1[index]?
Why the code is using l1.val?

Comment: `l1` and `l2` are not `list` objects. They're objects of type `ListNode`.

Comment: You're confusing Python's built-in `list` type with the linked lists that are implemented in the exercise. The word "list" appears in both, but they have little to do with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For brevity, they are written as lists, but they are not

If they really were simply `list` objects, you would be able to access the elements as `l1[0]` etc.

However they are in fact `ListNode` objects.

`l1` is, in effect,

```
{
    "val":2, 
    "next": {
        "val":4, 
        "next": {
            "val":3,
            "next":None
        }
    }
}
```

They are just writing `[2,4,3]` as a shorthand for the above structure. I agree that it is confusing.

#### `l1` and `l2` are specified to be of type `ListNode` when defined

```
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], ...
                                ##################
```

The code above means, "If parameter `l1` is present, it is of type `ListNode`".

The definition of `ListNode` is given in the previous block, beginning `class ListNode:`.

In other words, class `Solution` depends on class `ListNode`.

Comment: Appreciate to clear it out. Just one more question. l1 and l2 argument is inside def addTwoNumbers fuction which is inside Solution class. Why l1 and l2 is able to use .val? There is a .val function in python? Or it's calling self.val from ListNode? If it is from ListNode class, I don't know how it is calling .val from the other class.